# Should a web service (WebApi) know about the location of a calling client?

Tags: c#, angularjs, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I have written a web service (WebApi) which contains all of my service logic and is hosted up in the cloud. My colleague has written the front end part of this service using Angular.js.

The service contains security which means that if the client attempts to make calls to API's and isn't authenticated, or isn't authorised we throw a custom exception which then gets filtered by the WebApi using Exception filters (ExceptionFilterAttribute) and turned into an appropriate HttpResponseMessage.

```
 new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
```

or

```
new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Redirect)
{
    RequestMessage = context.Request,
};
```

In the special case of Unauthorised, the service is stating that the caller has not been authenticated and my colleague place code in the filter which then redirected the caller to the login page of the Angular.js website which to me seems incorrect - not least as this tightly couples the service to knowledge of the js website rather than supporting other client platforms (such as native apps).

The question is this, what is the correct approach for redirecting agnostic clients from a webapi website to the appropriate authentication portal? Should the redirect logic be removed from the service and handled purely by the calling client? or am I wrong and this logic belongs in the service?

Answer (score 0):

If you put the redirect logic in the service, it can only be used by this particular website.
The website should have its own logic on what to do when it receives a HttpResponseMessage with statuscode Unauthorized.
This will allow your service to be usable by other websites and apps.